# How to use resistor wattage formula

Tags: resistors

I've read about how to determine resistor wattage but it is not clear to me which V we need to consider in the calculation.

For example, this is a schematic of some electronics I am getting familiar with.
The 75R resistor (I assume to drop voltage before the 5V regulator), is rated at 5W.
The input voltage is around 26VDC from the 18VAC transformer winding after rectification.

As such, when calculating P=V^2/R, do we use 26VDC, or just the voltage that is dropped across the resistor?

Thanks!
[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the voltage across the resistor is important, as that's the only voltage it "sees."

Both the current through the resistor multiplied by the voltage it drops (\$P=IE\$) or voltage squared over resistance (\$P=\frac{E^2}{R}\$) will get you the nominal power dissipation. If you don't know the voltage drop, but know the current through the resistor, \$P=I^2R\$ also works. Choose a resistor that has some margin of error more power-handling capability, perhaps 10-20%.

Comment: I measured this with a DMM. In-Gnd = 26V, Out-Gnd=20V... I also measured across the resistor and it was (as expected) 6V. In that case, is only 1/2W required (as a minimum)?

Comment: Your logic is right, but you probably didn't test at maximum possible mains voltage (usually +10%). So you want a margin above that. I wouldn't go below 1W and I'd consider 2W better.

Comment: @BrianDrummond makes sense, thanks. As the schematic shows, a 5W was used originally and if I replace I will use the same.